# How to use Python's DictReader class in the csv library?

Tags: python, csv

I'm getting to grips with my first Python project and have got pretty stumped trying to use Python's csv.DictReader class to consume a CSV file.

Code is as follows:

```
import os
import csv

f = open('MyCsvFile.txt', 'rb')
d =  csv.Sniffer().sniff(f.read(1024), ',')
csvDict = csv.DictReader(csvfile = f, dialect = d)

for line in csvDict:
    print line['Balance Date ']
```

The csv file roughly looks like this:

```
"Balance Date ","Currency Code ","Main Account","Balance Float  - 1 Day",... forty more fields
"09/01/2011","EUR","4000519","                .00",...
"09/01/2011","GBP","4000519","                .00",...
"09/01/2011","JPY","4000519","                .00",...
```

Python is not liking my use of DictReader

```
g:\work\csvtest>python csvtest.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "csvtest.py", line 6, in <module>
    csvDict = csv.DictReader(csvfile = f, dialect = d)
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 2 arguments (2 given)
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Comment: as an 'and one' comment, I found it very useful to subclass DictReader and override it's storage to use an ordered dict.  This allowed for reading/editing/ and the writing the csv back in the same order

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [code supplied in the documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer), this would work better:

```
with open('MyCsvFile.txt', 'rb') as source:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(source.read(1024), ',')
    source.seek(0)
    csvDict = csv.DictReader(source, dialect)
```

Comment: I don't know why you have "dialect = d", that doesn't run for me, and is not what is displayed in the documentation.

Comment: This tell us how to open it not how to use the thing.

Answer (score 3):

You need to pass the `csvfile` as a positional argument, not as a keyword argument:

```
csvDict = csv.DictReader(f, dialect = d)
```

Comment: I've rolled back my answer to the original version. If you want to edit it to include the info from your answer you're welcome to; otherwise I won't duplicate it.

Comment: Since yours won't work, what's the point of rolling it back?  It seemed so much better to just provide the corrected code.